# How to collect characters/word typed next to # or @ in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with its contenteditable property set to true. When user types `'#'` or `'@'`, I would like to **get whatever he/she type until spacebar is pressed**. This way, I can bring suggestions from db according to the word he/she may type.
Please have a look at example below,

```
<div id="editableDiv" contenteditable="true">
    I may tweet from @twitter in the near #future
    <ul id="suggestUL"></ul>
</div>
```

As soon as user type `'@'` or `'#'`, I must be able to collect whatever he/she may type (according to  above example, after *@*  `t`, `tw`, `twi`, `twit`, `twitt`, `twitte` and `twitter`. And after *#* `f`, `fu`... `future`). After `'twitter'`, user typed *spacebar* so, the word collection must stop and must start from `#` again.

**Edited**
Code to get the pixel where I could display suggestion list

```
function getCaretPixelPos($node) {
    var offsetx = 0;
    var offsety = 0;

    var nodeLeft = 0,
    nodeTop = 0;
    if ($node) {
        nodeLeft = $node.offsetLeft;
        nodeTop = $node.offsetTop;
    }

    var pos = { left: 0, top: 0 };

    if (document.selection) {
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        pos.left = range.offsetLeft + offsetx - nodeLeft + 'px';
        pos.top = range.offsetTop + offsety - nodeTop + 'px';
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
        try {
            range.setStart(range.startContainer, range.startOffset - 1);
        } catch (e) { }
        var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (range.endOffset == 0 || range.toString() === '') {
            // first char of line
            if (range.startContainer == $node) {
                // empty div
                if (range.endOffset == 0) {
                    pos.top = '0px';
                    pos.left = '0px';
                } else {
                    // firefox need this
                    var range2 = range.cloneRange();
                    range2.setStart(range2.startContainer, 0);
                    var rect2 = range2.getBoundingClientRect();
                    pos.left = rect2.left + offsetx - nodeLeft + 'px';
                    pos.top = rect2.top + rect2.height + offsety - nodeTop + 'px';
                }
            } else {
                pos.top = range.startContainer.offsetTop + 'px';
                pos.left = range.startContainer.offsetLeft + 'px';
            }
        } else {
            pos.left = rect.left + rect.width + offsetx - nodeLeft + 'px';
            pos.top = rect.top + offsety - nodeTop + 'px';
        }
    }
    //console.log('pos left : ' + pos.left + ' pos top : ' + pos.top);
    //console.log($('#suggestUL'));
    $('#suggestUL').css('left', pos.left);
    $('#suggestUL').css('top', pos.top);
    //console.log('suggestUL left : ' + $('#suggestUL').css('left') + ' suggestUL top : ' + $('#suggestUL').css('top'));
};
```

This is how I am calling above function

```
var event = e || window.event;
    var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if (keyCode == 35 || keyCode == 64)
        getCaretPixelPos($('#editableDiv')[0]);
```

**PS:** I don't know why I have been fined by -2 reputation for Title. Anyway I edited title for more clarity. I am a learner, If I do any mistake in choosing title or asking question, kindly do suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have tried show that also.

Comment: ^Yup. If you haven't tried anything much yet, [input HTML5 event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMozilla_event_reference%2Finput) and/or just the regular [keyboardevent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) should get you started

Comment: @brokenHeart <- added code which I tried. Thanks.

Comment: you can get last entered character by using this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsahu/64m8M/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the issue from all of your inputs.
Here is the code

Function called on *KeyDown*

```
var fetchSuggestions = false;
var suggestForString = '';
function fnShowSuggestionUL(e) {
    var event = e || window.event;
    var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
    // KeyCode = 35 -> #
    // KeyCode = 64 -> @
    // KeyCode = 32 -> space
    // KeyCode = 13 -> Enter (Carriage Return)
    if (keyCode == 35 || keyCode == 64) {
        fetchSuggestions = true;
        suggestForString = '';
        $('#suggestUL').css('display', 'block');
        fnPositionSuggestUL();
    }
    else if (keyCode == 32 || keyCode == 13) {
        fetchSuggestions = false;
        suggestForString = '';
        $('#suggestUL').css('display', 'none');
        return;
    }
    if (fetchSuggestions == false)
        return;
    var data = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
    suggestForString = suggestForString + data;
    // TODO: bring suggestions from database and append them as list items to "suggestUL"
}
```

Position *suggestUL* at character `'@'` or `'#'`

```
function fnPositionSuggestUL() {
    var $node = $('#editableDiv')[0]
    var offsetx = 0;
    var offsety = 0;

    var nodeLeft = 0,
    nodeTop = 0;
    if ($node) {
        nodeLeft = $node.offsetLeft;
        nodeTop = $node.offsetTop;
    }

    var pos = { left: 0, top: 0 };

    if (document.selection) {
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        pos.left = range.offsetLeft + offsetx - nodeLeft + 'px';
        pos.top = range.offsetTop + offsety - nodeTop + 'px';
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
        try {
            range.setStart(range.startContainer, range.startOffset - 1);
        } catch (e) { }
        var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (range.endOffset == 0 || range.toString() === '') {
            // first char of line
            if (range.startContainer == $node) {
                // empty div
                if (range.endOffset == 0) {
                    pos.top = '0';
                    pos.left = '0';
                } else {
                    // firefox need this
                    var range2 = range.cloneRange();
                    range2.setStart(range2.startContainer, 0);
                    var rect2 = range2.getBoundingClientRect();
                    pos.left = rect2.left + offsetx - nodeLeft;
                    pos.top = rect2.top + rect2.height + offsety - nodeTop;
                }
            } else {
                pos.top = range.startContainer.offsetTop;
                pos.left = range.startContainer.offsetLeft;
            }
        } else {
            pos.left = rect.left + rect.width + offsetx - nodeLeft;
            pos.top = rect.top + offsety - nodeTop;
        }
    }
    //Create suggestUL if does not exist or destroyed
    fnCreateSuggestUL();

    $('#suggestUL').css('left', pos.left + 'px').css('top', (pos.top + 18)+'px');
};
```

I would like to thank one and all who answered/commented here.
Please optimize above code as much as possible so that one who in need gets perfect code.

**PS:** Works perfect in Chrome and firefox. *suggestUL* is not properly positioning in IE.
`Happy Coding!!`

Answer (score 2):

You can use following script, along with this you need to use some UL/LI element combination which will show one suggestion per line, once data is fetched from the sever. You can use the jQuery Ajax to to fetch the data from sever and create the ul/li list dynamically.

```
    var fetchData = false;
    var suggestionChar = '';
    $('#editableDiv').on('keypress',function(event){
         var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode.
         var hashKey; // Set keyCode for #
         var atKey; // Set keycode for @
         var spaceKey //SpaceKey code
        if(keyCode == hashKey || keyCode == atKey){
            fetchData = true
            suggestionChar = '';
            return; //flag is set now look out for next key cod.
        }
       else if ( keyCode == spaceKey ){
           fetchData = false;
           suggestionChar = '';
        }
       if( fetchData){
           var data = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
           suggestionChar = suggestionChar + data;
           // use "suggestionChar" for fetching the data from server.
           // fetch suggestions  from Server.
           // On success call back create the dynamic list of ul/li which will show the suggestion to user. You need to bind the user click event and/or keypress event for ul/li so that user can select the suggestion using mouse and keyboard along with 'Space' key.
        }
    })
```

Comment: I have idea about this but is this is the only possible way? I have a very little knowledge on regex. I guess regex must solve my issue. what do u say?

Comment: Regx will give you the text string your looking for. But for the event when to start and stop. You would require similar approach. If you just use the Regx and change event for the div that will work too. But with this approach there is no regx, i find this better because you have access to character which user would require suggestion without regx. The above solution would require little refinement, to collect all the characters entered after #/@.

Comment: Let me try with this concept. If you could get time, please help me out to sort the issue. Thanks

Comment: I have updated the solution with required refinement. This should work now.

Answer (score 1):

I've made this stuff (textarea only) : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/sL2sZ/. I've tried to match your requirements but it's a bit more time-consuming to make things work using an editable DIV. I've decided to give up and to take inspiration from StackOverflow. You might pick up some ideas from my code in order to achieve your goal, hopefully. 
More on `getCaret()` here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/263796/1636522.

---

Shirt-tail...

Currently, you are able to get the pixel position of the caret, while my code brings you a way to get the word around the current caret index. The missing link is a cross-browser solution to get the caret index from an editable DIV (this is where I gave up, too much work for me), indeed, the current version of `getCaret()` only accepts a textarea.

In other words, all you have to do is to modify the body of `getCaret()` in order to make it work with an editable DIV. Once you have the index, you have the word around it through `getWord()`, so, you can check if it's prefixed with "@", then display appropriate suggestions using `getCaretPixelPos()`.

```
$('textarea').on('click keyup', function isAt() {
    var idx = getCaret(this),
        text = $(this).val(),
        word = getWord(text, idx);
    $('p').html([
        '"', word, '" ', word.charAt(0) === '@' 
        ? '<span style="color:blue">is prefixed</span>' 
        : '<span style="color:red">is not prefixed</span>'
    ].join(''));
}).focus();

function getWord(s, i) {
    var r = /\s/g;
    if (!i || r.test(s[i - 1])) return '';
    while (i && !r.test(s[--i])) {}
    r.lastIndex = i && ++i;
    return s.slice(i, (
        r.exec(s) || { index: s.length }
    ).index);
}
```

Comment: <- Thanks Wared. Let me work on it. I hope this must solve my issue.

Comment: Sorry Wared, I failed to get caret index from div. I posted my answer. Please have a look at it. Optimize it with your knowledge. I am a poor guy in regex. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm busy for now. Here is a little help : https://www.google.fr/search?q=get+caret+position+contenteditable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = '';
$('#editableDiv').keyup(function(e){
  if($(this).val() == '@' || $(this).val() == "#"){
    if(e.keyCode !=32){  
      str += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    }
  }
});
alert(str);
```

Comment: may need to use `$(this).text()` instead of `$(this).val()`

Comment: Yes sure! Thanks for advice. This is just my idea. I knows there are a lot of way to do. :D